# Extending the bounds on a Google Map slightly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the map.fitbounds to fit all the markers I have set with in the map viewport,  but the markers are right up against the sides of the viewport and I want to zoom out just a little.

I have tried

```
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
```

but is moves out too much and seems to zoom with the viewport to the top.
Ideally I want to emulate what happens when I scroll the mouse wheel 1 click to zoom out just a little.

You can see the sample file with the issue here.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1367679/MapLifeEvents.html

As you can see ideally you want to be out just a little to show the markers at the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom levels in google maps are not continuous so you can't adjust the level the way you want.What you can do is create a [LatLngBounds object](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) and use it's extend method the markers you have and lastly use the [panToBounds method of map](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) to make the map fit your markers.

In the description of this last method you will see the following

> Pans the map by the minimum amount necessary to contain    the given
>   LatLngBounds.It makes no guarantee where on     the map the bounds
>   will be, except that as much of the    bounds as possible will be
>   visible. The bounds will    be positioned inside the area bounded by
>   the map type    and navigation (pan, zoom, and Street View) controls, 
>   if they are present on the map. If the bounds is larger    than the
>   map, the map will be shifted to include the    northwest corner of the
>   bounds. If the change in the    map's position is less than both the
>   width and height    of the map, the transition will be smoothly
>   animated.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be giving me the same result as fitBounds, but I will play around and see if I can get a compromise.

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is not possible in google maps the way you want it.In google earth the zoom levels are more close to what you want.